# C# and SQL Server 2008 : how to handle null from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am selecting `max(id)` from database which are grouped by date. Sometimes there might be situation where date does not have any id. That time it rising error so how to handle it n assign to int variable.

```
SqlCommand maxid = new SqlCommand("select max(block) from blocks_allocation where date='" + DR.ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString() + "'", con);

SqlDataReader maxrd = maxid.ExecuteReader();

if (maxrd.Read())
   block_no = int.Parse(maxrd["block"].ToString()) + 1;

maxrd.Close();
```

Comment: You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And looks like you are storing your `DateTime` values as a string since you have a column named as `date`. Don't do that. It is a bad desing.

Comment: sorry for my bad coding...can u please suggest me solution

Comment: As already asked: what is the error?

Answer (score 2):

`SqlCommand` returns [`DBNull.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if the value is null, so if you have a query that could return null values you need to test against `DBNull.Value` first, like this:

```
var date = DR.ItemArray.GetValue(7).ToString();
const string sql = "SELECT MAX(block) FROM blocks_allocation WHERE date = @date";
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
    var maxBlock = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    block_no = maxBlock == DBNull.Value ? null : (int?) maxBlock;
}
```

(This assumes that `block_no` is a [nullable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) int). I've also changed a few other things:

- If q query returns a single value you can use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Read` etc...
- You should use [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) blocks instead of manually closing / disposing of objects.
- You shouldn't build dynamic SQL as it can lead to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - I've modified the query to use a parametrized query instead.

I've used the [inline-if syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to set `block_no`, but you can also use a standard if should you prefer:

```
if (maxBlock == DBNull.Value)
{
    block_no = null;
}
else
{
    block_no = (int?) maxBlock;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check whether the max(id) is null, if it so then return 1 using ISNULL()

```
select isnull(max(block),1) from blocks_allocation
```